# How is 下総国一の宮 pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

From [dictionary](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A6%99%E5%8F%96%E7%A5%9E%E5%AE%AE) article on a certain shrine:

香取神宮は　千葉県香取市香取にある神社。**下総国一の宮**。祭神は経津主神。鹿島神宮とともに軍神として尊崇を受けた。

しもうさのくに。。。？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> [下総{しもうさ}国{のくに}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E7%B7%8F%E5%9B%BD) [一{いち}の宮{みや}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E5%AE%AE)